# PostgreSQL: change order of columns in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a huge query with about 30 columns.
I ordered the query with:

```
Select *
From
.
.
.
order by id,status
```

Now I want that in the result to present columns in certain way.
The `id` column will be first, followed by `status` column and then all the rest.

is there a way to do that (**without manually specifying** 30 column names in select). Something like: `Select id,status, REST`

Comment: You can do something else like this [_Select id,status, *_] yeap it duplicate your is and status column

Comment: Never ever use a * in production code, you don't know what you're selecting.

Comment: @Frank I Simplified my situation, whatever the solution is here I will know how to modify it for my real query.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you all columns except those you don't want to

```
SELECT id, status,' || array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT 'o' || '.' || c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns As c
            WHERE table_name = 'table_name' 
            AND  c.column_name NOT IN('id', 'status')
    ), ',') || ' FROM officepark As o' As sqlstmt
```

Comment: I don't want to remove any column. I just want 2 of them first.

Comment: @John then just change it to include them again at the start `SELECT id, status,  '  || ....`

Answer (score 1):

The "select *" will return the fields in the order in which they were listed when the table was created. If you want them returned in a particular order, just be sure to create the table with that order.

Comment: My database is very complex I'm not about to change anything in it's design. All I'm asking is if there is a query manipulation that can solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it repeatly, you could create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO as
SELECT id, status, mydesiredorder
```

Or just a view,don't forget to move index constraint and foreign keys. If you must do it just once, was faster specify 30 columns than ask here